# How to identify the key pressed fromEvent() rxjs

Tags: angular

I use fromEvent() from rxjs for listening to a input box which is used for searching a list. I want to skip the key 'TAB' when the user press that key. How to modify the below code in such a way that we skip the TAB key from the key pressed? And then search other key pressed.

```
const keyup6$ = fromEvent(searchBox6, 'keyup')
    keyup6$.pipe(
      map((i: any) => i.currentTarget.value),
      debounceTime(1000))
      .subscribe(x => {
        this.countryId = x;
        console.log(this.countryId);
        this.fetchCustomersCount();
        this.searchCustomer();
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant you want to prevent the navigation out of the textbox on tab key. It appears you can only grab the Tab key presses on keydown event.

The example shows merging both keydown and keyup events into a single stream. The keydown will filter for Tab keypresses and prevent the default behavior. Note this is likely an accessibility concern.

After filtering out the keydown, it will receive the keyup for Tab, which I also filter out of the keyup event.

```js
const searchBox6 = document.getElementById('searchBox6');
const keydown6$ = rxjs.fromEvent(searchBox6, 'keydown');
const keyup6$ = rxjs.fromEvent(searchBox6, 'keyup');
const {
  map,
  debounceTime,
  tap,
  filter,
  ignoreElements
} = rxjs.operators;

rxjs.merge(
    keydown6$.pipe(
      // Only take tab keys Can also use event.keyCode, which says it is deprecated, but your
      // code is using const, so I think you would be okay using KeyboardEvent.key...
      filter(event => event.key === 'Tab'),
      // Prevent the default event
      tap(event => event.preventDefault()),
      // Don't care about doing anything with keydown from here
      ignoreElements()
    ),
    keyup6$.pipe(
      // Tab keys are now emitting keyup because the keydown behavior was prevented
      filter(event => event.key !== 'Tab')
    )
  ).pipe(
    // Your code...
    rxjs.operators.map((i) => i.currentTarget.value),
    debounceTime(1000))
  .subscribe(x => {
    console.log(x);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.6.0/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
<input id="searchBox6">
```

Comment: This is working thank you very much. But the tab key itself is not switching to next input box. Basically i wanted to make a tab and move to next input element , but just wanted to stop searching on the Tab key. I have 6 input text boxes each of them search a specific value in a table(DB). The problem is when a user press a Tab key it searches on the next input element thinking that user entered some value. This fix is preventing the Tab key press so it is not navigating to next element itself.